# Find all $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying: $\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$,$f(m+n)+f(m-n)=2f(m)f(n)$

Tags: functions

Find all $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying: $\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$,$f(m+n)+f(m-n)=2f(m)f(n)$

I don't know how to solve?

Comment: Your first statement is false because $f(n)=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ is a solution of the functional equation (this is because you divided by $f(m)$, which could be $0$). This implies that you have to modify the second and third statement also.

Comment: Also, if $m,n \in \mathbb{N}^+$, is it OK to take $n=0$?

Comment: Ah... so careless I am, I've edited the problem. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying for $m=n=0$ gives $2f(0)=2f(0)^2$ so $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$.

#### First case : $f(0)=0$

$f(m)+f(m)=2f(m)f(0)=0\implies f(m)=0$ for $m>0$

$f(n)+f(-n)=2f(0)f(n)=0\implies f(-n)=0$

> $f(n)=0, \forall n\in\mathbb Z$

#### Second case : $f(0)=1$

$f(n)+f(-n)=2f(n)\implies f(-n)=f(n)$

Let's call $a=f(1)$

$f(n+1)+f(n-1)=2f(n)f(1)=2af(n)$

So if we note $u_n=f(n)$ then it satisfies thre relation : $u_{n+2}-2au_{n+1}+a_n=0$

Characteristic equation is $r^2-2ar+1=0$ whose $\Delta=4(a^2-1)$

#### subcase $a=1$

$r=1$ so $u_n=(bn+c)1^n=bn+c$

$f(0)=c=1$ and $f(1)=b+c=1$ so $b=0$

> $f(n)=1,\forall n\in\mathbb Z$

#### subcase $a=-1$

$r=-1$ so $u_n=(bn+c)(-1)^n$

$f(0)=c=1$ and $f(1)=-(b+c)=-1$ so $b=0$

> $f(n)=(-1)^n,\forall n\in\mathbb Z$

#### subcase $|a|<1$

*Note: since $f(1)=a$ is an integer, then $a=0$ is forced, but let's find it back later... for the fun.*

This makes $\Delta<0$ there are two roots $r=a\pm i\sqrt{1-a^2}$

Note that $r\bar r=a^2+1-a^2=1$ so $|r|=1$ and we can associate a trigonometric line $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ with $\cos(\theta)=a$.

$f(n)=b\cos(n\theta)+c\sin(n\theta)$

$f(0)=b=1$ and $f(1)=b\cos(\theta)+c\sin(\theta)=ba+c\sqrt{1-a^2}=a$ so $c=0$.

$f(n)=\cos(n\theta)$

But we require that $f(n)\in\mathbb Z$ so $f(n)$ can be only $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Thus $\theta$ can only be $\{0,\frac{\pi}2,\pi\}$ also $|a|=|\cos(\theta)|<1$ so the only possibility is $\theta=\frac{\pi}2$.

> $\displaystyle f(n)=\cos(\frac{n\pi}2)=\frac{i^n+(-i)^n}2,\ \forall n\in\mathbb Z$

#### subcase $|a|>1$

This makes $\Delta>0$ there are two roots $r=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-1}$

$f(n)=br^n+c\bar r^n$

$f(0)=b+c=1$ and $f(1)=br+c\bar r=(b+c)a+(b-c)\sqrt{a^2-1}=a$ so $b-c=0$.

> $\displaystyle f(n)=\frac{r^n+\bar r^n}2$ with $r=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-1}$ and $|a|>1$ integer$

For $u>1$, we can also make the substitution $a=\cosh(u)$ in this case $r=\cosh(u)\pm\sinh(u)=e^{\pm u}$

And $f(n)$ becomes $\displaystyle f(n)=\frac{e^{nu}+e^{-nu}}2=\cosh(nu)$

A similar formula arises for $a<-1$ this time $a=-\cosh(u)$ and there are $(-1)^n$ appearing.

---

We see coming the Tchebyshev polynomials invoked by **fractal1729**.

$\begin{cases}
T_n(a)=\cos(n\cos^{-1}(a)) & |a|\le 1\\
T_n(a)=\cosh(n\cosh^{-1}(a)) & a>1\\
T_n(a)=(-1)^n\cosh(n\cosh^{-1}(-a)) & a<-1\\
\end{cases}$

The case $a=1=\cos(0)$ is compatible with $\theta=0$ and $f(n)=\cos(n\times 0)=1$

The case $a=-1=\cos(\pi)$ is compatible with $\theta=\pi$ and $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$

So in the end all cases except the trivial case $f=0$ can be rewritten

$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid]{f(n)=T_n(a) \text{ where } f(1)=a}$

---

*Edit: How to handle the case of uncertainty about $f(0)$ if we restrict the functional relation to stand only for strictly positive integers ?*

The study above regarding the induction relation for $u_n$ stays valid, the only thing that changes is that we cannot determine $c$ with the initial condition $f(0)=1$ but the other condition $f(1)=a$ stands.

- For $a=1$

$f(n)=bn+c=(1-c)n+c$

verifying $f(m+n)+f(m-n)=(1-c)2m+2c=2f(m)\implies f(n)=1\implies c=1$

- For $a=-1$

$f(n)=(bn+c)(-1)^n=((1-c)n+c)(-1)^n$ but since $(-1)^{m+n}=(-1)^{m-n}$

verifying $f(m+n)+f(m-n)=2f(m)(-1)^{m+n}\implies f(n)=(-1)^n\implies c=1$

- For $a=0$

$f(n)=bi^n+c(-i)^n=c(i^n+(-i)^n)=2c\cos(\frac{n\pi}2)$

verifying the additive $\cos$ relation gives $4c=8c^2\implies c=\frac 12$ and $f(0)=2c=1$

- For $|a|>1$

$f(n)=br^n+c\bar r^n=c(r^n+\bar r^n)=2c\ T_n(a)$ and we conclude like previously that $c=\frac 12$.

Finally $f(0)$ can be determined a posteriori, and $f(0)=1$.

Comment: So great! But as the mistake I've made, $m,n\in \mathbb{N}^+$, if this, the premise is still valid? Thanks.

Comment: It is not an issue at all because $f(n)=f(-n)$ is immediate, so everything can be extended to whole $\mathbb Z$. And don't worry about people who claim $0\notin\mathbb N^+$, half the planet think the opposite.

Comment: I think you are right, but I still can't figure a formal way to handle the premise if $0 \notin \mathbb{N}^+$ (I do think I'm in the half planet who believe this...). You conduction is really clear, it is what I want, thank you so much!

Comment: It can be shown that $f(0)=1$ is a consequence, see my latest edit.

Answer (score 3):

The trivial solution is $f(n)=0$ for all $n$.  Now let's forget about the trivial solution since it's boring.

Your functional equation resembles the cosine sum-to-product formula.  Recall that $$\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)=2\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta).$$
This made me think of [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), which are defined by the recursive relation $$T_{m+1}(x)=2T_1(x)T_{m}(x)-T_{m-1}$$ and satisfy $\cos(nx)=T_n(\cos(x))$.  This is exactly what you get when you plug in $n=1$ into your functional equation!  Hence I think the solution is $f(n)=T_n(f(1))$.

Comment: Nice observation!  I'm not sure how you would use this to prove that there are no other solutions, though.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury See my post, I think there aren't.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury You should be able to prove there are no other solutions by starting with any particular value of $f(1)$ and then inducting upwards, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, none of your three equations must hold, because you said that the function identity only holds for *positive* $m$ and $n$.

So what can we say?  Well, taking $n = 1$, we see that

$$f(m+1) = 2 f(m) f(1) - f(m-1)$$

for positive $m$.  That is, the value of $f(m)$ for $m > 1$ is completely determined by the value of $f(m)$ for smaller values of $m$, which means that $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ completely determine the values of $f(m)$ for $m > 1$.

Now, taking $m = 1$, we have

$$f(1 - n) = 2 f(1) f(n) - f(n + 1)$$

for $n > 0$.  We can get any negative input we like on the right by taking a positive value of $n$, and the terms on the right will feature values of $f$ at positive inputs.  So all together this tells us that $f$ is completely determined by its values at $0$ and $1$.

Okay, so let's write $a := f(0)$ and $b := f(1)$.  We have

$$f(m+1) = 2 a f(m) - f(m-1), \qquad f(1) = b, \qquad f(0) = a$$

This is a second-order linear recurrence, just like the Fibonacci sequence.  There's a standard technique to solve these.

Once you do that you can figure out what happens for negative inputs, and then finally you can check to see which of the solutions satisfy your original functional equation in general.

Comment: Note that the solutions to the specific recurrence relation you wrote down are exactly the linear functions!

Comment: @GregMartin: Huh?  Which recurrence?

Comment: um ... a special case (of the first one) that I was imagining was the whole thing. (namely $f(1)=1$) never mind...!